# Building String in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, recursion, permutation

I am beginner with C and  I want to make all possible strings from given string with repetitions(which has max length 8). I am little bit desperate about pointers. I have this code(Input is for example "abcd"):

```
void permute(char *str, char *p_ch, int length);

int main() {
   input = malloc(8 * sizeof(char));
   fgets(input, 11, stdin);
   int n = strlen(input);
   permute(NULL, NULL, n);
   return 0;
}
void permute(char *str, char *p_ch, int len) {
   if (str == NULL) {
      char str[len];
      *p_ch =&str[0];
      permute(str, p_ch, len);
      return;
   }
   if (strlen(str) != len) {
       for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
           *p_ch = input[i];
           permute(str, (p_ch + 1), len);
       }
   }
   else {
       printf("%s", str);
   }
```

}

So the input what i want to is:
*AAAA
AAAB
AAAC
AAAD
AABA
AABB
.
.
.etc*

Could someone tell me where i make the mistake? I work with java, where this algorithm work well, so i have only problem with different language. thanks a lot

Comment: Those are not permutations. Are you sure you fully understand the problem?

Comment: and what is it? It is all possible permutations from given input string @iharob

Comment: All possible permutations are `abcd`, `acdb`, `adcb` ... and so on. You don't repeat characters.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, i want to make all possible strings from given input with repetitions

Comment: You need to solve the problem on paper first. It's not something I would like to solve. Yet it would be very interesting to see the solution.

Comment: @iharob but i have this problem solved, but only in java and in C it does not work

Comment: On line two of permute you are redefining str. you may want to call str = malloc(sizeof(char) * len)

Comment: @user2666293 Please don't use `sizeof(char)`, it's useless and just makes the code hard to read.

Comment: @user2666293 yes it is due to that i dont know a length of given string, only thing, that i know that the string won't be bigger than 8

Comment: 1) `malloc(8 * sizeof(char))` you want max length 8, So change to `malloc((8+1) * sizeof(char))` 2) `fgets(input, 11, stdin);` should be `fgets(input, 9, stdin);` 3) `int n = strlen(input);` might include newline. 4) `permute(NULL, NULL, n);` Input string is not used.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I don't get it where is problem in case 3) and 4)

Comment: ah 4) `input` is global variable. sorry. 3) You want to include a newline character in the permutation? E.g. "abc\n" ->"ab\nc"

Comment: "Tell me where I made a mistake" is overly broad.

Comment: 4)`char str[len];` --> `char str[len+1];` 5) `*p_ch = input[i];` --> `*p_ch = input[i]; p_ch[1] = 0;`

Comment: 6) `*p_ch =&str[0];` --> `p_ch =&str[0];`  [fix DEMO](http://ideone.com/kgYNIi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using all of the comments I assembled a version of the program that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void permute(char *str, char *p_ch, int length);

char* input;

int main() {
    input = malloc(8+1 * sizeof(char));
    fgets(input, 9, stdin);
    int n = strlen(input);
    if(input[n-1] == '\n')n--;//remove newline if fgets included it
    permute(NULL, NULL, n);
    return 0;
}
void permute(char *str, char *p_ch, int len) {
    if (str == NULL) {
        str = malloc(len+1);
        memset(str,0,len+1);
        p_ch = &str[0];
        permute(str, p_ch, len);
        free(str);
        return;
    }
    if (strlen(str) != len) {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            *p_ch = input[i];
            p_ch[1] = 0;
            permute(str, (p_ch + 1), len);
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("%s ", str);
    }
}
```